# how to made new post for sharepoint newsfeed webpart through custom webpart

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

i have a requirement to made new post through custom web part and this must be shown on sharepoint 2013 news feed web part

i am new with share point after the lot of googleing find a list of news feed "PublishedFeed".

but now also i am not know the procedure.

please help?

Answer (score 1):

It is all part of the Social API available.  Here is a good reference for the common tasks on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163237.aspx#bkmk_CommonTasks

> Publish a root post to the current user's feed
>   (specify null for the target)
>
> CSOM: [CreatePost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.social.socialfeedmanager.createpost.aspx)
>
> JSOM: [createPost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj667802.aspx)
>
> REST: POST http:///_api/social.feed/my/Feed/Post and pass the restCreationData parameter in the request body
>
> SSOM: [CreatePost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialfeedmanager.createpost.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();    
    var feedManager = new SP.Social.SocialFeedManager(clientContext);

    // Create the post content.
    var postCreationData = new SP.Social.SocialPostCreationData();

    postCreationData.set_contentText("your message");

    //Publish the post
    feedManager.createPost(null, postCreationData);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(postMicroBlogSucceeded, postMicroBlogFailed);
```